# Bootstrap Modal Login with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a website where I have implemented Bootstrap's modal component as a login form.

I have my login script working correctly (tested without the modal), however, it obviously is not able to display errors as the modal closes before any errors are displayed. My best bet to get the errors displaying is to use `AJAX`. I've attempted implementing `AJAX` into it, but seem to be failing miserably (it's not something I'm familiar with).

Here's the code I've tried so far:

**index.php**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function login(username, password, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", "login.php", true);
    xhr.responseType = "json";
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var data = xhr.response;

        if (data["status"] === "failure") {
            callback({
                "errorCode": data["errorCode"],
                "errorMessage": data["errorMessage"]
            });
        } else {
            callback(null, data["redirect"]);
            $("#error").append(errorMessage);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    });
}
</script>
```

--- // ---

```
    <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="loginForm">
                        <div id="error"></div>
                    <form id="login" action="index.php" method="post">
                        <div class="input-container">
                            <label for="username">Email or Username</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" required class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-container">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" required class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-container">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="true" id="remember" />
                            <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="submit-container">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-login">SIGN IN</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>  
        <h2><span>or</span></h2>    
        <div class="social-signin">
            <a href="#" class="facebook">Sign in with Facebook</a>
            <a href="#" class="google">Sign in with Google+</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <p>Need an account? <a href="sign-up">Sign up here.</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**login.php**

--- // ---

```
 login_complete($user_id);

    $output = [];

    $output["status"] = "success";

    echo json_encode($output);
    exit;
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("status" => "failure", "errorCode": $result[0], "errorMessage": $ERRORMSGS[$result[0]]));
}
```

My question is, how can I properly implement `AJAX` into my Bootstrap modal login form, to successfully display error messages (such as "Incorrect username and/or password")? At the moment, no error is displayed and the user isn't authenticated (it just goes back to index.php).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: console.log something in your `login` function to determine if it's being called when you _submit_ the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something to get you started: this is basically what I use and is pretty similar to what you have. It uses ajax to send the form to `login.php`, which returns a json response. The magic happens in `login.html` and is really quite easy: just add a `messages` div to the modal, and then target that with jQuery to add your messages and appropriate Bootstrap alert classes.

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</button>

            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <form id="form" role="form">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div id="messages"></div>
                                YOUR FORM ELEMENTS HERE
                            Username: <input type="text" name="username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('#form').submit(function(e) {

                var form = $(this);
                var formdata = false;
                if(window.FormData){
                    formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
                }

                var formAction = form.attr('action');

                $.ajax({
                    type        : 'POST',
                    url         : 'login.php',
                    cache       : false,
                    data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
                    contentType : false,
                    processData : false,
                    dataType: 'json',

                    success: function(response) {
                        //TARGET THE MESSAGES DIV IN THE MODAL
                        if(response.type == 'success') {
                            $('#messages').addClass('alert alert-success').text(response.message);
                        } else {
                            $('#messages').addClass('alert alert-danger').text(response.message);
                        }
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php

$success = true;

if($success == true) {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'success', 'message' => 'YAY'));
} else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'message' => 'WHOOPS'));
}

die($output);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed response. Unfortunately this didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: This has been tested and works - you can see it in action by just clicking the LOGIN button in the modal - you'll get a success message. So if it's not working, you didn't implement it correctly or you have problems elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I've done a bit of tinkering, and it now appears to sign in after refreshing the page. (The modal does not automatically close, nor does the page refresh to log the user in - but it's still one step closer than I was before, also the error messages don't seem to display)

Comment: You don't really want the modal to automatically close because the user won't see the messages. Regardless, to close the modal just add `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` after the success message.

Comment: The messages display in the example I provided. If they're not working for you, you haven't implemented them correctly. Regardless of the rest, your question was "how can I properly implement AJAX into my Bootstrap modal login form, to successfully display error messages" which I think I've sufficiently answered :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement *AJAX*, the button which does the submission has a type of `submit` and fires the `submit` event on the form, which will not let your code even reach the function that does the AJAX call.

Instead, you could change the type of the button *from `submit` to `button`*, and add the following handler to trigger when the form submits:

```
$('#login').submit(function(){
      //prepare your username, password and callback
      login(username, password, callback);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Ahmad, unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. The form no longer appears to submit.

Comment: what is in your console when you click the submit button?

Comment: Nothing is appearing in my console when I click the submit button.

Comment: And, indeed, you HAVE to prevent your form from immediately submitting. After getting the response from the ajax call, then only you should redirect the user to some page you are intending to using JS `window.location` or any other alternate.

Comment: I'n not quite sure I understand what you mean, I'm sorry.