# Bootstrap success alert upon form submition via javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, submit, alert

I've been searching the internet for hours to try to understand how to make a dismissible green alert slide down (non-modal) when a user submits a form. I'm thinking it has something to do with form validation but not sure. Please help.

The code isn't working, because when I click submit on the form, nothing happens. The  validation is not applying to the form. (the form action attribute has been left empty.) method="post"

I am using a form processing script provided by the server (not sure if that makes a difference.)

so my question is: how can I "link" the submit button to send the form to the sever, then show a dismissible success alert via jQuery that will fit into a col-md-4?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I didn't explain very well. However, I have edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified way of how you can do it within a Bootstrap modal. All we're doing here is checking if the form has been submitted via jQuery, then showing the message in a modal.

[Here's how to incorporate that with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32285872/2101328)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">

            <div id="messages" class="hide" role="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <div id="messages_content"></div>
            </div>

            <form id="form" method="post">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $('#form').submit(function(e) {
                $('#messages').removeClass('hide').addClass('alert alert-success alert-dismissible').slideDown().show();
                $('#messages_content').html('<h4>MESSAGE HERE</h4>');
                $('#modal').modal('show');
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked (so that a first), everything is have tried hasn't. however I'm trying to make a dismissible success alert, pop up just below the submit button. so non-modal.

Comment: I've updated it. No more modal, alert slides down from top.

Comment: You good sir are a genius! Just for understanding,  what is the "e.preventDefault();" doing?

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` stops the form from submitting so jQuery can handle it. http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: but it submits after jQuery has handled it right?

Comment: Not really. What you would do in that instance is handle the submission with jQuery's `.post()` method, which will take all of the form's contents and submit them to a PHP script - or whatever language you choose - via ajax, and then you use jQuery to check the returned value of the script and show the success (or error) message.

Comment: I'm using an action in the form tag to a server form handling  address, would that make any difference?

Comment: Possibly. Only way to find out is to test, test, test. :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

What is happening.. when you submitted any page(form.php) to some other page (form-submit.php).. message is passed through URL using header function to form.php.. in form.php that message is picked using get method..

### **form.php**

```
<?
if($_GET['submitted'])
{?>
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  Form Submitted Successfully
</div>
<?}?>
<form ... action='form-submit.php'>
.
.
</form>
```

### **form-submit.php**

```
// All submission query.. 
// at the end, after performing all necessary actions.. need to come to form.php page.. so we will use header("");

header("location:form.php?submitted=successfully");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm sorry but where do you use header? and i edited my post to explain a bit more.

Comment: This worked for me but it would not work without me using `<?php` in the appropriate spots. `<?` would not work for me.