# How to submit a contact form with Google recaptcha v2 and PHP with a Boostrap success alert

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a contact form on a website, and I am trying to submit the form using Google recaptcha v2, (select the boxes which have a certain image in them). At the moment, the form successfully sends and is received exactly as I want it to; however, I want to create a 'success' alert using Bootstrap, but for some reason this is not working.

If you take a look at the last part of my PHP file I have the following code snippet:

```
if($responseKeys["success"]) {

        mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

    } else {
        echo '<h2>This has been unsuccessful according to our security checks</h2>';
    }
```

And the 'mail' command seems to work. But anything else I try to put in there, for example

```
echo '<h2>success!</h2>'
```

for example, it doesn't get rendered. Ideally, upon a success submit I would like the following to take place:

- The form to refresh to blank
- A success alert using Bootstrap show at the top of the page

But I am having trouble implementing these.

Here is the entire PHP file:

```
<?php

    $Fname = $_POST['Fname'];
    $Lname = $_POST['Lname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $email_from = "Your website";
    $email_subject = "You have a new submission form from Your Website";
    $email_body = "First Name: $Fname.\n".
                    "Last Name: $Lname.\n".
                    "Email Address: $email.\n". 
                    "Telephone Number: $number.\n". 
                    "Company Name: $company.\n". 
                    "Message: $message.\n";

    $to = "hello@yourwebsite.co.uk";
    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

    $captcha;
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
        $email=$_POST['email'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['message'])){
        $message=$_POST['message'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
    if(!$captcha){
        echo '<h2>Please check the "I am not a robot" checkbox"</h2>';
        exit;
    }
    $secretKey = 'somesecretlettersandnumbers';
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    // post request to the server
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . urlencode($secretKey) . '&response=' . urlencode($captcha);
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response, true);
    // should return JSON with success as true
    if($responseKeys["success"]) {

        mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

    } else {
        echo '<h2>This has been unsuccessful according to our security checks</h2>';
    }
?>
```

And here is the HTML form:

```
<form action="contact.php" id="contact-form" method="POST" role="form">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_name">First Name*</label>
                    <input id="form_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="Fname" placeholder="David" required data-error='Please fill in your first name'>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_lastname">Last name*</label>
                    <input id="form_lastname" type="text" class="form-control" name="Lname" placeholder="Beckham" required data-error="Please fill in your last name">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_email">Email address*</label>
                    <input id="form_email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="becks@example.com" required data-error="Please provide your email address">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_number">Contact number*</label>
                    <input id="form_number" type="number" class="form-control" name="number" placeholder="01234567890" required data-error="Please provide a contact number">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_company">Your company name</label>
                    <input id="form_company" type="text" class="form-control" name="company" placeholder="Ex-footballers r us">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>  
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_message">Your message*</label>
                    <textarea id="form_message" class="form-control" name="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Here's my message" required></textarea>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="datasitekeynumbersandletters"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-brand btn-block" name="submit" value="Send enquiry">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

I have tried following this tutorial:
[Bootstrap success alert upon form submition via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287271/bootstrap-success-alert-upon-form-submition-via-javascript)

Edited to add the only JS I have for this file:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

without success.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Provide your javascript code also. How are you receiving the response?

Comment: So I haven't even got started on the JS as I don't know what should go in the JS. The recaptcha isn't very well explained and there aren't very good tutorials on it. The only JS I have for this particular form has been added above.